# in react how to use reusable component as React Component to pass into react-router-dom Component prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following react reusable component, can i use it as react component in the react-router-dom here? I m new to react, thank you so much for your help.......................................................................................................

when i use this code i get error: var Component: ((props: Props) => JSX.Element) | JSX.Element
JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.

```
 const ImageFirst = ({ imgSrc, title, desc, link, linkTitle }: Props) => {
      return (
        <div className="SRFoods">
          <div className="SRFoodsImg">
            <img src={imgSrc} alt="" width="100%" height="auto" />
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{desc}</p>
            <h4>
              For More Info, Go to: &nbsp;
              <a href={link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                {linkTitle}
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

//App.js page

```
import ImageFirst from "./components/Pages/ImageFirst";
import SRFoodsImg from './assets/srproducts.png'
import Home from "./pages/Home";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const routes = [
    { path: "/", name: "Home", Component: Home },
    { path: "/food/sragro", Component: <ImageFirst
    imgSrc={SRFoodsImg}
    title="SR Agro"
    desc="testofdesc"
    linkTitle="http://srfoods.com.np"
    link="http://srfoods.com.np"
    /> },
  ];
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <>
        <Navbar />
        {routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
          <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
            {({ match }) => (
              <div className="page">
                  <Component />
                </div>
            )}
          </Route>
        ))}
        <Footer />
      </>
    </BrowserRouter>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Seems like a really simple thing to test. Have you tried it? I suspect it won't work and you'll need to render an anonymous component, i.e. `component: () => <ImageFirst ......./>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly certain you can't pass a ***fully instantiated*** component to the `component` prop of a `Route`, but you *can* pass an anonymous functional component.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    Component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/food/sragro",
    Component: () => (
      <ImageFirst
        imgSrc={SRFoodsImg}
        title="SR Agro"
        desc="testofdesc"
        linkTitle="http://srfoods.com.np"
        link="http://srfoods.com.np"
      />
    ),
  },
];
```

This would be nearly the equivalent of defining a component ahead of time.

```
const CustomImageFirst = () => (
  <ImageFirst
    imgSrc={SRFoodsImg}
    title="SR Agro"
    desc="testofdesc"
    linkTitle="http://srfoods.com.np"
    link="http://srfoods.com.np"
  />
);

...

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    Component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/food/sragro",
    Component: CustomImageFirst,
  },
];
```